# Categorizing an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to know what kind of optimization problem is the following (so I can look for an appropriate solver):

$max \sum_{i=1}^{28} exp(C_i + k_i * log(a_i*x_i)) $

subject to

$ \sum_{i=1}^{28} x_i = Z$

In this case all $C_i, k_i, a_i, Z$ are known.

Thank you very much

Comment: Something missing from your second summation

Answer (score 0):

By reformulation your problem is $\max_x \sum r_i (a_ix_i)^{k_i}$ which is a convex problem for $0 < k_i < 1$ ($r_i$ is positive as it is $e^{C_i}$). Use favorite nonlinear solver or reformulate as second-order cone/power cone/exponential cone, or find analytical solution.